# PHP script called from javascript(ajax/jquery) echos as an alert dialog rather than original page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to be able to pass data from a java-script script to php and send new data from the php script back to java-script. However, when I send the data to php and echo it in the new php script, the echoed content is sent through an alert.

A simplified (& incorrect) version of what I'm trying to do is as follows

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"> </script>
</head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$.ajax({ url: 'loadContent.php',
  data: {action: 'HEYO'},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
    alert(output);
  }
});
```

loadContent.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
      $action = $_POST['action'];
      echo $action;
  }
 ?>
```

What this code currently does is display an alert with whatever text is sent through script.js to loadContent.php. What I would like it to do is echo the content to the original page.

Comment: `alert(output);` It's doing what you're telling it to do.

Comment: you need to paste this content inside any div or other html element on your html page. alert() is doing the exact job for which it meant for

Comment: do you want to put the response of loadContent.php in the originating page or alert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to paste this content inside any div or other html element on your html page. `alert()` is doing the exact job for which it meant for

So code need to be:-

HTML code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"> </script>
</head>
<body> 
  <div id="result"></div><!-- created a div to represent the output of ajax code-->
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery code:-

```
$.ajax({ url: 'loadContent.php',
  data: {action: $('html').html()},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
    $('#result').html(output); // paste the output to the div
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the output of loadContent.php to be put into the page you could use something like

```
$.ajax({ url: 'loadContent.php',
      data: {action: 'HEYO'},
      type: 'post',
      success: function(output) {
        $('body').html(output);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Uuuh... still alerting.

Comment: @waterloomatt It must be ambigous, i thought he wanted the php to `echo` the content of the original page not put it on the page